# Conditional hiding of a control based on PopUp value in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, binding, popup

I have an `NSPopUp` with several values, one of them is "custom". Custom does not have an index or tag equal to zero. Let's say it is the fourth item, with a tag of also 4.

How can I check for the selection of "custom"? I want to hide/show another control based on this selection. This other control should only appear when I select "custom". I can use the "hidden" binding, hopefully, but how to configure it?

Comment: need a bool to track, if that popup index value gets changed...

Comment: Is there an elegant way to keep that bool in sync, with as little code as possible? I can make something but it might be 10 times as long as really needed...

Comment: Here is the solution... check and revert me back

Comment: I will, thanks Anoop. I can't do this until Friday, unfortunately, but I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution...

Create one property "onOffValue" to track the selection of "Custom" from popup.

One action to alter the onOffValue.

In .h

```
@property(assign) BOOL onOffValue;
- (IBAction)popUp:(id)sender;
```

In .m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.onOffValue=NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)popUp:(id)sender {
    if ([[sender title]isEqualToString:@"Custom"]) {
        self.onOffValue=NO;
    }
    else{
        self.onOffValue=YES;
    }
}
```

In IB, select the control which you want to Hide-Unhide.

In Binding Inspector, In Hidden option Bind to Your Class (in my case it is AppDelegate)

Set the model key path to `self.onOffValue`

Thats it!!!

EDIT:
[image]

Here is the [link](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5245431/buttonbinding-zip-34k?da=y) where you can download the file for help...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's an easy way to do this with bindings, but it can be done easily with the action method of the popup. Just set the hidden property of your other control based on the value of the titleOfSelectedItem:

```
-(IBAction)selectionChanged:(NSPopUpButton *)sender {
    if ([sender.titleOfSelectedItem isEqualToString:@"Custom"]){
        self.otherControl.hidden = YES;
    }else{
        self.otherControl.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - He asked, with bindings, hopefully -- if you still have to use the action method, then adding the binding is just extra work, and doesn't get you anything more than just using the action method.

Comment: I agree. But what to do, when a requirement is there like him :D Somehow it has to be solved although it is a long procedure

Comment: Thank you both *very* much for the help. As usual, the code is simpler than the question! Both answers are valuable, and I eventually implemented the one from rdelmar. But the answer from @Anoop Vaidya was also very useful with detailed instructions!